# Python creating a dictionary and swapping these into another file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two tab delimited .csv file. From one.csv I have created a dictionary which looks like:

```
'EB2430': ' "\t"idnD "\t"yjgV "\t"b4267 "\n',
'EB3128': ' "\t"yagE "\t\t"b0268 "\n',
'EB3945': ' "\t"maeB "\t"ypfF "\t"b2463 "\n',
'EB3944': ' "\t"eutS "\t"ypfE "\t"b2462 "\n',
```

I would like to insert the value of the dictionary into the second.csv file which looks like:

```
"EB2430"    36.81   364 222 4   72  430 101 461 1.00E-063   237
"EB3128"    26.04   169 108 6   42  206 17  172 6.00E-006   45.8
"EB3945"    20.6    233 162 6   106 333 33  247 6.00E-005   42.4
"EB3944"    19.07   367 284 6   1   355 1   366 2.00E-023   103
```

With a resultant output tab delimited:

```
'EB2430'   idnD   yjgV   b4267   36.81   364 222 4   72  430 101 461 1.00E-063   237
'EB3128'   yagE   b0268   26.04   169 108 6   42  206 17  172 6.00E-006   45.8
'EB3945'   maeB   ypfF   b2463   20.6    233 162 6   106 333 33  247 6.00E-005   42.4
'EB3944'   eutS   ypfE   b2462   19.07   367 284 6   1   355 1   366 2.00E-023   103
```

Here is my code for creating the dictionary:

```
f = open ("one.csv", "r")
g = open ("second.csv", "r")
eb = []
desc = []
di = {} 

for line in f:
    for row in f:
        eb.append(row[1:7])
        desc.append(row[7:])

di = dict(zip(eb,desc))
```

Sorry for it being so long-winded!! I've not been programming for long.

Cheers!

Sat

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could more usefully use the Python standard library [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) module here. rather than perform the text processing parts youself "manually".  E.g.:

```
import csv
with open("one.csv", "r") as f:
  rows_one = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))
with open("second.csv", "r") as g:
  rows_two = list(csv.reader(g, delimiter='\t'))
rows_totl = [r + s[1:] for r, s in zip(rows_one, rows_two)]
with open("total.csv", "w") as h:
  csv.writer(h, delimiter='\t').writerows(rows_totl)
```

The `with` statement is one of the jewels of Python 2.6 (it's also usable in 2.5, but only if you `from __future__ import with_statement`!-) -- as used here, it gives you an open file and ensures it gets closed as soon at the `with` body's done... plus, it has a zillion more uses, e.g. for locks and all sorts of your own custom-coded "context managers".

Comment: Alex,  
In addition to using the csv module, you are using the "with" statement. It might be nice to point out why you made that change as well.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest, instead of hand-parsing CSV file use [csv](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html) that is built-in. It takes care of delimiters, character escaping etc. It's API is simple, too:

```
import csv

# Auto-detector of this particular CSV dialect (delimiters and such)
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(open('one.csv').read())

# csv.reader yields every row found in the file using the given dialect
rows = csv.reader(open('one.csv'), dialect = dialect)

# [list comprehension][2]
resulting_dict = dict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in rows)
```

You can refactor the code into a function and use it for both files (coding from memory, though, beware for errors).

Now you've got two dicts for two files, let's say `dict1` and `dict2`, you can combine them:

```
combined_dict = dict((key, dict1[key] + dict2[key]) for key in dict2)
```

Writing it to a .csv file is also straightforward:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('second.csv', 'w'), delimiter = '\t')
for key, values in combined_dict:
    writer.writerow(key, *values)
```

Definitely check out the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html) for the more detailed reference.

**Edit:** My solution doesn't take line ordering into account (dict is unordered). There are two solutions:

- if you're running Python 3 or Python 2.7, use collections.OrderedDict
- otherwise, you need to store the order of the lines - for example, while reading the second file break the list comprehension into standard `for` statement and store the headers in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv
reader1 = csv.reader(open('input1.csv'), delimiter = '\t')
reader2 = csv.reader(open('input2.csv'), delimiter = '\t')
csvwriter = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'),delimiter = '\t')
while True:
    row1 = reader1.next()
    if row1:
       row2 = reader2.next()
       new_row = row2 + row1[1:]
       csvwriter.writerow(new_row)
    else:
        break
```